# My app is crashing when Apple review my app but we cannot replicate the crash using the same build configuration in development

Tags: app-store, ios13, appstore-approval

I have submitted an app to the app store via fastlane but it is getting rejected because when Apple run the app on iOS 13.1.3 it crashes on launch. We've run the app on a real device running this exact OS and the app runs without issue.

In attempt to replicate the issue as closely as possible we have distributed the app to ourselves via Fabric.io. The build sent to Fabric.io uses the same build configuration as the script that deploys the app to the app store (therefore it's unlikely to be an issue with optimisation). The only difference (from what I can see) is the provisioning profile the build is signed with ("Adhoc" for crashlytics and "App Store" for the app store).

The app was then loaded onto a real iPhone 7 running iOS 13.1.2. The app launched without issue. All of our certificates and provisioning profiles are in date.